# A question about affine Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles, geometric-representation-theory

I am reading Sorger's *Lectures on the Moduli of* $G$*-bundles*, and I am confused about a detail in the proof of proposition 5.3.2., where he proves that the $G$-bundle description of affine Grassmannian agrees with the quotient description as algebraic spaces.

Here is the setup: let $X$ be a smooth, connected and complete curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, $G$ an affine algebraic group over $k$, $x \in X$ a point, $U= \operatorname{Spec} R$ for $R$ some $k$-algebra. We also let $X_{U}$ be the base change, $X^{*}=X\ \backslash \{x\}$, and $D=\operatorname{Spec} (k[[z]]) $

Now, let $E \to X_{U}$ be a principal $G$-bundle, and $\tau$ a trivialisation
$\tau : E|_{X^{*}_{U}} \to X_{U}^{*}\times G$. The claim is then that we can find a faithfully flat homomorphism $U' \to U$ and a trivialisation $\sigma '$ of the pullback $E|_{D_{U'}} \to D_{U'}$ under the natural map $D_{U} \to X_{U}$.

He gives a sketch argument saying that if we restrict to the central fibre we can assume the bundle has a section and then extend it using smoothness, but that does not quite make sense to me. Would anyone have a more explicit proof, or could give some more details about his argument?

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the argument does not make sense? Trivializing a bundle is equivalent to giving a section. If you have a bundle over $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} R[[t]]$ and a section over $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} R$, you can extend the section to $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} R[[t]]/t^n$ because the bundle is smooth over the base. In the limit you get a section of the bundle over $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} R[[t]]$.